# "Invalid .internal.selfref" warning NO CALLING list() INVOLVED

Tags: r, reference, data.table

Why do I get the annoying warning?

```
initialize = function() {
table = data.table(1:10)
colnames(table) <- "old.col"
table
}
dt <- initialize()
dt[, new.col := 5]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning message tells you everything you need:

> Warning message: In `[.data.table` `` (dt, , `:=`(new.col, 5)) `` :
>   Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow)
>   copy of the data.table so that := can add this new column by
>   reference. At an earlier point, this data.table has been copied by R
>   (or been created manually using `structure()` or similar). Avoid `key<-`,
>   `names<-` and `attr<-` which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole
>   data.table. Use set* syntax instead to avoid copying: `?set`, `?setnames`
>   and `?setattr`. Also, in R<=v3.0.2, list(DT1,DT2) copied the entire DT1
>   and DT2 (R's `list()` used to copy named objects); please upgrade to
>   R>v3.0.2 if that is biting. If this message doesn't help, please
>   report to datatable-help so the root cause can be fixed.

The `.internal.selfref` pointer refers to the location in memory of the `data.table`. Using `key<-`, `names<-` or `attr<-` apperently causes R to make a copy of the `data.table` which needs another place in memory.

So, instead of using `colnames` you should use `setnames`:

```
initialize = function() {
  table = data.table(1:10)
  setnames(table,"V1","old.col")
  table
}
dt <- initialize()
dt[, new.col := 5]
```

Now you won't get a warning because the `data.table` is updated by reference without making a copy and thus keeping the same `.internal.selfref` pointer to the location in memory.

Comment: A suggestion to the creators of data.table: There are more situations than `key<-`, `names<-`, `attr<-` that causes this warning to be output. One such is if we combine datatables using `purrr::map_dfr()`. A suitable warning should be added to use `rbindlist()` instead of any other `rbind` variant.